# Unable to select QnABot in bot template (web app bot)

Tags: botframework, azure-qna-maker

I'm trying to create a web app bot in the Azure Portal, but I can't select the QnA template. It's supposed to be like a selector but appears just as text.

How can I connect my bot to the QnA Maker service?

[image: QnA Selection in Bot Service Creation]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to create the web app bot directly in the Azure portal. You can do this, and hook up your QnA knowledge base (KB), but it sounds like you want a more simple approach. To do this, you need to start from within the qnamaker portal itself, from the "Publish" screen of your knowledge base. First Publish the KB, then you'll see the screen with a "Create Bot" button - it works as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/tutorials/create-qna-bot) (I've just tested to confirm).

When you start from this "Publish" screen, the Web App Bot has a "QnA Auth Key" section - see the bottom of this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: @Hiram, was this able to help?

Comment: Thanks for triying to help, the problem it's that i can't select in the Bot template (In the steep of the Web App Bot Service in zure portal) the Question and Answer (c#) option, it's appears as text an not as an option. In the image in my question you can see with the green arrow how it's look like, and for example in this guide looks that they selected it as an option https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/52223.azure-bot-framework-introduction-to-azure-bot-service-and-qna-maker.aspx         Thanks for your help and time

Comment: Yes I can see that you don't have the option, but it looks like you are going to Azure to start this process - you must START in the QnA maker website, like I've described

Comment: I did the QnA Steps before to go to Azure, actually i have my three parameters: QnA Knowledge Base Id, QnA Endpoint HostName, and QnA Auth Key, but the Azure steep in that describe it's my problem. any clue of why that happend?